# Passing data from View to Controller for sql statement in Model in CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I have a simple form of images that a user can click on and depending on the image clicked on a modal dialog will appear with a list of data from the database. I have this working for one whereby I state the specific column name in the mysql statement not via a variable. I would like to be able to know how/where I pass the value of the image input from the view to the controller so that it can be used in the mysql statement in the view..I already pass the mysql statement from the controller to the model to the view. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated as I am brand new to CI and abit confused.Thanks!

CONTROLLER:

```
      <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class App extends MY_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    log_message('debug', 'App controller has been initialized');
}

public function toolsmodal()
{
    $Dept = $this->input->post('submit');
    //echo $Dept;
    $this->load->model('tools_model');
    $tools = $this->tools_model->getTools($Dept);
    $data['tools'] = $tools;
    $data['view'] = 'datatables';
    $this->load->view('templates/default', $data);
}

public function index()
{


    $data['view'] = 'datatables';
    $this->load->view('templates/default', $data);


}

public function welcome()
{
    $data['view'] = 'welcome';
    $this->load->view('templates/default', $data);
}

public function datatables()
{
    // You can safely delete this method.  It is an example.
    $data['view'] = 'datatables';
    $this->load->view('templates/default', $data);

}


    }
```

MODEL:

```
      class Tools_model extends CI_Model
      {
public function getTools($Dept)
{  

    //$query = $this->db->query("select rname,decription,DRI,developer, golive from web.reportdash where AppleStore = 'Yes'");
    $this->db->select('rname, decription, DRI, developer, golive');
    $this->db->where($Dept, 'Yes');
    $query = $this->db->get('web.reportdash');

    $tools = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $tools[] = $row;
    }

    return $tools;
}
```

}
    ?>

VIEW:

```
     <table>
      <tr> 
<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:300px;font-size:14px;color:       #ffffff;"><input type='image' id='filters-trigger-applestore' src="<? echo             base_url("/_assets/img/store.png"); ?>" name='submit' value='Store'>      <br>AppleStore</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:300px;font-size:14px;color:    #ffffff;">                 <input type='image' id='filters-trigger-storef' src="<? echo   base_url("/_assets/img/finance.png"); ?>"   name='submit' value='Finance'><br>Finance</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:300px;font-size:14px;color: #ffffff;"><input type='image' id='filters-trigger-storel' src="<? echo base_url("/_assets/img/logistics.png"); ?>" name='submit' value='Logistics'>     <br>Logistics</td>
  </tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:300px;font-size:14px;color: #ffffff;"><input type='image' id='filters-trigger-storeman' src="<? echo base_url("/_assets/img/manufacturing.jpg"); ?>" name='submit' value='Manufacturing'><br>Manufacturing</td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:300px;font-size:14px;color: #ffffff;"><input type='image' id='filters-trigger-storect' src="<? echo base_url("/_assets/img/control.jpg"); ?>" name='submit' value='ControlTower'><br>Control Tower</td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:300px;font-size:14px;color: #ffffff;"><input type='image' id='filters-trigger-storeom' src="<? echo base_url("/_assets/img/OM.jpg"); ?>" name='submit' value='OrderManagement'><br>Order Management</td>
</tr>
```

```
<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:300px;font-size:14px;color: #ffffff;">  <input type='image' id='filters-trigger-stores' src="<? echo base_url("/_assets/img/sales.jpg"); ?>"                name='submit' value='Sales'><br>Sales</td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>

 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="filters-trigger-applestorem not-displayed modal1 hide fade in" style="overflow:auto;">
<button type="button" id='close' class="close" data-dismiss="filters-trigger-applestorem">×</button>   
<table class="table table-bordered smaller-font margin-top-medium" style="margin: 0;">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Report Name</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>DRI</td>
<td>Developer</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
                <?php foreach($tools as $tool):
                ?>
                    <tr class="padding-larger-right table-header"><td><?= $tool->rname; ?>    </td>
                    <td class="smaller-padding vertical-centred"><?= $tool->decription; ?></td>
                    <td class="smaller-padding vertical-centred"><?= $tool->DRI; ?></td>
                    <td class="smaller-padding vertical-centred"><?= $tool->developer; ?></td>
                <?php
                endforeach ?>



                </tbody>
            </table>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi just modify your model, for loop in model $tool array will always have only last row every time its over write old array here is your modified

```
    class Tools_model extends CI_Model
      {
public function getTools($Dept)
{  

    //$query = $this->db->query("select rname,decription,DRI,developer, golive from web.reportdash where AppleStore = 'Yes'");
    $this->db->select('rname, decription, DRI, developer, golive');
    $this->db->where($Dept, 'Yes');
    $query = $this->db->get('web.reportdash');

    return $query->result();

}

} ?>
```

you can easily loop in view now

Comment: thanks for this, thats a great help.Can I ask where I should loop at in my view?

Comment: yes loop in view, in your way you were doing loop twice and you need data to show in view, can you please accept this answer

Comment: sorry but this still doesn't work.The value from the input must not be being passed correctly to the model as I get this error "Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'" when I click on the images input. Also the form changes the URL to app/toolsmodal and does not redirect back to the view or open/populate the modal dialog with the data

Comment: Can someone please help. I don't understand why the value is not being posted or why the page keeps reloading and will not load the modal dialog...Any help would be much appreciated!